# Wordpress my rewrite rule not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create new rule. I put this code in theme `functions.php`

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^test/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=22&funcs=$matches[1]');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Now I'm going to `www.domain.com/test/123` and I'm getting 404 error. Anyone have idea why is that?

Comment: did you resave the permalinks? (in the admin section), also are you using pretty permalinks?

Comment: this was the problem! thanks you! :)

Comment: so i'm trying to put /%postname% in the pretty permalinks (permalink_structure), but now its not working again. any suggestions?

Comment: In the rewrite rule, what is 'funcs' being used for in the query? Also want to confirm you have a page with the id of 22.